# Splitting a URL-formatted String using Java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a `String` which is a website URL, such as *"http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/default/files/pic.jpg"*. I want to split this String so that I can change some of the path values, such as changing */files/* to */newfolder/*.

Is this easily achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] afterSplit = yourString.split("files/");
String newString = afterSplit[0];
newString += "/newfolder/";
newString += afterSplit[1];
```

With a standard String.split() method, since you asked for splitting. newString is the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the part after the last "/" and append "newfolder/pic.jpg"

```
String str = "http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/default/files/pic.jpg";
str.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "newfolder/pic.jpg";
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best (most flexible) possibility (or even more general `str.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "newfolder" + substring(s.lastIndexOf("/"));`)

Answer (score 1):

Use a replace function and replace "files/" by "files/newfolder/", for example.

Comment: Yh..i get it..Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The solution with replace fails if the path before 'files' also contains 'files', for example in `http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/files/default/files/pic.jpg`

Comment: Good objection, but maybe not relevant in his setup.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String parts[] = String.split(oldPath, "files\");
String newPath = parts[0] + "newfolder\" + parts[1];
```

I haven't tested it but in theory it should work. There could be a problem with the backslash in the regular expression, but if so, its easy to fix.

Regards,

-Harry

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replace("pic.jp" ,"newfolder/pic.jpg");
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/default/files/pic.jpg";
string.replace("files/", "files/newfolder/");
```

Comment: wow!..look like the simplest method...Thanks Chandra Sekhar...let me check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
String input = "http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/default/files/pic.jpg";
int lastIndexOfSlash = input.lastIndexOf('/');
String result = input.substring(0, lastIndexOfSlash + 1) + "newfolder/" + input.substring(lastIndexOfSlash + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
String s = "http://www.abcd.com/en/sites/default/files/pic.jpg";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.insert(sb.lastIndexOf("/"), "/newfolder");
s = sb.toString();
```